# failed to get some values from dynamic multiple input fields using reactjs

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

i have implemented dynamic input fields that are created whenever u click add Product button but  i dont why i  can only pick itemAmount values  but not  input values for productId and itemQuantity. 
iam using react v16.0.2

```
productItems: Array(2)

 0: {"": "450000"} //productId is empty
1: {"": "670000"} //why does it only pick itemAmount but not the quantity and productId
```

i happen to use react-bootstarp for styling.

```
constructor(){
this.state = {
  invoice_notes: '',
    itemValues: [] //suppose to handle the productItems that are being added.
}
//for the product items
handleItemChange(i,evt){
 const {name,value} = evt.target;
 const items = [...this.state.itemValues]
 items[i] = {[name]: value}
 //this.setState({items}) //it just has empty values
 this.setState({itemValues: items}) //works but empty for productId n amount
```

}

```
addProductItem(){
  const item = {
    productId: '',
    itemQty:'',
    itemAmount: ''
  }
  this.setState({itemValues: [...this.state.itemValues, item]})
```

}

```
createItemsUI(){
 //Use #array.map to create ui (input element) for each array values. 
 //while creating the fields, use a remove button with each field,
  return this.state.itemValues.map((elem,i)=> //recall arrow functions do not need return statements like {}
           <div key = {i}>
               <FormGroup controlId="formControlsSelect">
                  <ControlLabel>Product</ControlLabel>
                  <FormControl
                     componentClass="select"
                     name = "productId"
                     bsClass="form-control"
                     value = {this.state.itemValues[i].productId}
                     onChange =  {this.handleItemChange.bind(this,i)}>
                      <option value = "" disabled>{'select the product'}</option>
                        {productOptions.map((item,i)=>{
                           return(
                              <option 
                                   key = {i} label= {item}  value = {item}
                               >
                               {item}
                              </option>
                           )
                       })}
                  </FormControl>
                </FormGroup>
                 <FormInputs
                     ncols={["col-md-4","col-md-4"]}
                     proprieties={[
                       {
                         label: "Quantity",
                         type: "number",
                         bsClass: "form-control",
                         defaultValue:this.state.itemValues[i].itemQty,
                         onChange: this.handleItemChange.bind(this,i)
                      },
                      {
                        label: "Amount",
                        type: "number",
                        bsClass: "form-control",
                        defaultValue: this.state.itemValues[i].itemAmount,
                        onChange: this.handleItemChange.bind(this,i)
                     }
                   ]}
                />
              <Button onClick = {this.removeProductItem.bind(this,i)}>Remove</Button>
           </div>  
        )
  }
```

}
please i have read many similar questions so i think iam on the right track.. I prefer to be inquisitive
So after @steve bruces comment, i made some changes to the handleItemChange function but i happen to get almost the same behaviour of not picking the productId and itemQty input values.

```
handleItemChange(i,evt){
 const name = evt.target.getAttribute('name');
 console.log('let see name', name) //i getting the name of the atrribute --> productId, itemQty, ItemAmount
 const items = [...this.state.itemValues]
 items[i] = {[name]: value}
 this.setState({itemValues: items})
```

}
This is what happens if i try using setState({items}) as suggested by similar questions

```
items[i] = {[name]: value}
 this.setState({items})
RESULT of the productItems when u  click the submit button
productItems: Array(2)
0: {productId: "", itemQty: "", itemAmount: ""}
1: {productId: "", itemQty: "", itemAmount: ""}
```

but when i use this.setState({itemValues: items}) atleast i can get the last value of the itemAmount

```
productItems: Array(2)
0: {itemAmount: "25000"}
1: {itemAmount: "45000"}
length: 2
Any help is highly appreciated
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe your error is coming up in your `handleItemChange(evt,i)` function.

It looks like you want to return "placeholder" by destructuring `evt.target`. This does not work because evt.target doesn't understand "name". I think you want to try `evt.target.attribute('name')` to return the name. `evt.target.value` will return the value of that input and `evt.target.name` does not exist so it returns undefined.

A small tip. You no longer have to bind functions in your constructor. You can can get rid of your constructor and update your functions to be arrow functions.

For example this:

```
handleItemChange(i,evt){
 const {name,value} = evt.target;
 const items = [...this.state.itemValues]
 items[i] = {[name]: value}
 //this.setState({items}) //it just has empty values
 this.setState({itemValues: items}) //works but empty for productId n amount
```

becomes this:

```
handleItemChange = (i,evt) => {
 // const {name,value} = evt.target;
 //updated that to this here
 const { value } = evt.target; 
 const name = evt.target.attribute("name"); 
 ...
```

And the call to in your `onChange` would look like this:

```
onChange = {() => { this.handleItemChange(evt,i)}
```

you must add the `() =>` in your onChange so the `handleItemChange` is not invoked on every render *before* it's actually changed. It's invoked the moment you pass the params evt, and i. So the `() =>` function is invoked onChange and then handleItemChange(evt,i) is invoked.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for taking your time to answer this question.
so i made some changes and iam still stuck at the same problem.
At first I tried using evt.target.attribute('name') but got this error
`TypeError: evt.target.attribute is not a function`
so i made some changes to the code and it was able to get the attribute name>
`

Comment: oh gotcha. interesting. let me take another look at this

Comment: maybe try `getAttribute` instead of `attribute`. let me know if that works. if not no worries I am happy to help :)

Comment: yes getAttribute('name') was able to get the attribute value but the overall result of productItems array has funny values as shown by additional comments that I made above

Comment: where are you getting the value of the event target?

Comment: sorry i forgot to include it in the above code while asking. let me add it there
`const {value} = e.target`
the same problem was stil persisting even when the value = evt.target.value was there
iam not good at using the stackoverflow thread to show the flow of the answers